# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.how to redirect to login page if session is null

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I open web-forms page on a browser but i am getting this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Kindly review the code snippet, what i am doing wrong

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoginUser"].ToString()) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CustomerId"].ToString()) == false)//error
   {
      if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() == "admin")
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = true;
         fillusers();
      }
      else if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() != "admin" && Session["CustomerId"].ToString() == "True")
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = false;
         //fillusers();
      }
      else
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = false;
      }

      FillProjectList();
      Pnl_Link.Visible = false;
      Pnl_Status.Visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
   }
}
```

how to make if session is null it should redirect to login.aspx. without throwing run time exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `Session["LoginUser"]!=null` in your first if condition after

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (Session["LoginUser"]!=null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoginUser"].ToString()) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CustomerId"].ToString()) == false)//error
   {
      if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() == "admin")
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = true;
         fillusers();
      }
      else if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() != "admin" && Session["CustomerId"].ToString() == "True")
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = false;
         //fillusers();
      }
      else
      {
         DDlUsers.Visible = false;
      }

      FillProjectList();
      Pnl_Link.Visible = false;
      Pnl_Status.Visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        if (Session["LoginUser"]!=null && Session["CustomerId"]!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LoginUser"].ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CustomerId"].ToString()))//error
            {
            if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() == "admin")
                {
                DDlUsers.Visible = true;
                fillusers();
                }
            else if (Session["LoginUser"].ToString() != "admin" && Session["CustomerId"].ToString() == "True")
                {
                DDlUsers.Visible = false;
                //fillusers();
                }
            else
                {
                DDlUsers.Visible = false;
                }
            FillProjectList();
            Pnl_Link.Visible = false;
            Pnl_Status.Visible = false;
            }
        else
            {
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
            }

        }
```